# Copy files to newly created directories - php

Tags: php, directory, copy

There are two files `a.php` & `b.php` in a directory named `a`

Directory path is as following:

```
/home/user/public_html/directory/username/a/
```

Is it possible to automatically copy these files whenever any new sub-directory is created in directory `a`?

For example,

```
 /home/user/public_html/directory/username/a/x/
 /home/user/public_html/directory/username/a/y/
```

The files should be copied from `a` to `x and y` whenever these are created.

Any reference shall be well appreciated.

Comment: Nope that's not the job of `PHP`. You can do it on your server level or setup a cron to keep checking for that. But PHP itself doesn't know about that copying of files unless you copied files using the script itself

Comment: @Hanky 웃 Panky , thanks for useful info, but is it possible to copy files by assigning cron job based on the appearance of new directories when time is an ignorance factor here? can you provide me some resource urls? thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on who initiates the creation of files. If it makes the PHP then the solution may be to use a server queues (such as gearman or rabbitmq).  In this case, the queue server starts copying files instantly and muliti thread as soon as they are added to the queue.